# openpyxl - is there a way to get real value instead of formula

Tags: python, openpyxl

is there a way to get the real value instead of the formula of a cell printed out with openpyxl library?

I read a lot about that, according to stackoverflow the openpyxl library doesnt offer this option which is bad. 
The only solution which I found here was to manually open the excel file and save the formulas as hard coded values.
I am trying to automate my processes and dont want to do anything manually.

```
import openpyxl

template = openpyxl.load_workbook('import_spendesk_datev.xlsx') #Add file name
temp_sheet = template['Import']


print(temp_sheet.cell(row=2,column=13).internal_value)
```

I expect that I can print out the real value of the cell instead of the formula.

Thanks a lot for any help. Maybe another python library for manipulating excel which offers this?

Comment: `openpyxl.load_workbook('import_spendesk_datev.xlsx',data_only = True)`.

Comment: This is covered by the documentation.

Comment: @Henry Yik i tried and read about the data_only idtrue. Still didn’t fix the problem. Maybe i need to mentioned that the formulas i create with openpyxl .

Comment: @Charlie Clark. I will look in the documentation. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`xlrd`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I have a single value in an excel workbook that uses a formula RANDBETWEEN:
[image]

Code to grab the value:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook, cellname

book = open_workbook(r'path_to_excel\test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
print(sheet.cell(0,0).value)
65.0
```